# Apache Ignite exception: Caches have distinct sets of data nodes

Tags: java, exception, ignite

I am starting with Apache Ignite and I was following Ignite tutorial on Apache website. I run into exception below. It seems I caused two different data sets and I can't manage to synchronize them or choose one over another.

This happens when I start Ignite from command line first then code in before class method updates it. Then test code starts new node. I would assume they would be in sync.

Code:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.ignite.Ignite;
import org.apache.ignite.IgniteCache;
import org.apache.ignite.IgniteException;
import org.apache.ignite.Ignition;
import org.apache.ignite.cache.query.FieldsQueryCursor;
import org.apache.ignite.cache.query.SqlFieldsQuery;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;

public class IgniteTest
{
    @BeforeClass
    public static void beforeClass() throws Exception
    {
        // Register JDBC driver.
        Class.forName("org.apache.ignite.IgniteJdbcThinDriver");

        // Open JDBC connection.
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ignite:thin://127.0.0.1/");

        // Create database tables.
        try (Statement stmt = conn.createStatement()) {

            // Drop existing tables
            stmt.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Person");
            stmt.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS City");

            // Create table based on REPLICATED template.
            stmt.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE City (" +
            " id LONG PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR) " +
            " WITH \"template=replicated\"");

            // Create table based on PARTITIONED template with one backup.
            stmt.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE Person (" +
            " id LONG, name VARCHAR, city_id LONG, " +
            " PRIMARY KEY (id, city_id)) " +
            " WITH \"backups=1, affinityKey=city_id\"");

            // Create an index on the City table.
            stmt.executeUpdate("CREATE INDEX idx_city_name ON City (name)");

            // Create an index on the Person table.
            stmt.executeUpdate("CREATE INDEX idx_person_name ON Person (name)");
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void test_01_HelloWorld() throws Exception
    {
        try (Ignite ignite = Ignition.start("examples/config/example-ignite.xml"))
        {
            // Put values in cache.
            IgniteCache<Integer, String> cache = ignite.getOrCreateCache("myCache");
            cache.put(1, "Hello");
            cache.put(2, "World!");
            // Get values from cache
            // Broadcast 'Hello World' on all the nodes in the cluster.
            ignite.compute().broadcast(() -> System.out.println(cache.get(1) + " " + cache.get(2)));
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void test_ignite() throws Exception
    {
        // Connecting to the cluster.
        try (Ignite ignite = Ignition.start("examples/config/example-ignite.xml"))
        {
            // Getting a reference to an underlying cache created for City table above.
            IgniteCache<Long, City> cityCache = ignite.cache("SQL_PUBLIC_CITY");

            // Getting a reference to an underlying cache created for Person table above.
            IgniteCache<PersonKey, Person> personCache = ignite.cache("SQL_PUBLIC_PERSON");

            // Inserting entries into City.
            SqlFieldsQuery query = new SqlFieldsQuery(
                "INSERT INTO City (id, name) VALUES (?, ?)");

            cityCache.query(query.setArgs(1, "Forest Hill")).getAll();
            cityCache.query(query.setArgs(2, "Denver")).getAll();
            cityCache.query(query.setArgs(3, "St. Petersburg")).getAll();

            // Inserting entries into Person.
            query = new SqlFieldsQuery(
                "INSERT INTO Person (id, name, city_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");

            personCache.query(query.setArgs(1, "John Doe", 3)).getAll();
            personCache.query(query.setArgs(2, "Jane Roe", 2)).getAll();
            personCache.query(query.setArgs(3, "Mary Major", 1)).getAll();
            personCache.query(query.setArgs(4, "Richard Miles", 2)).getAll();

            // next example

            // Querying data from the cluster using a distributed JOIN.
            SqlFieldsQuery query2 = new SqlFieldsQuery("SELECT p.name, c.name " +
                " FROM Person p, City c WHERE p.city_id = c.id");

            FieldsQueryCursor<List<?>> cursor = cityCache.query(query2);

            Iterator<List<?>> iterator = cursor.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                List<?> row = iterator.next();

                System.out.println(row.get(0) + ", " + row.get(1));
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IgniteException
    {
        try (Ignite ignite = Ignition.start("examples/config/example-ignite.xml"))
        {
            // Put values in cache.
            IgniteCache<Integer, String> cache = ignite.getOrCreateCache("myCache");
            cache.put(1, "Hello");
            cache.put(2, "World!");
            // Get values from cache
            // Broadcast 'Hello World' on all the nodes in the cluster.
            ignite.compute().broadcast(() -> System.out.println(cache.get(1) + " " + cache.get(2)));
        }
    }
}

class City
{
    private long id;
    private String name;
}

class Person
{
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private long city_id;
}

class PersonKey
{

}
```

Exception:

```
javax.cache.CacheException: Caches have distinct sets of data nodes [cache1=SQL_PUBLIC_CITY, cache2=SQL_PUBLIC_PERSON]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.twostep.GridReduceQueryExecutor.stableDataNodes(GridReduceQueryExecutor.java:499)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.twostep.GridReduceQueryExecutor.nodesForPartitions(GridReduceQueryExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.twostep.GridReduceQueryExecutor.query(GridReduceQueryExecutor.java:591)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.IgniteH2Indexing$8.iterator(IgniteH2Indexing.java:1339)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.QueryCursorImpl.iterator(QueryCursorImpl.java:95)
    at org.lhasalimited.ecosystem.business.statestore.ignite.impl.IgniteTest.test_ignite(IgniteTest.java:111)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
*emphasized text*   at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:538)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)
```

Comment: Looks weird.  
What are cache configuration for cache1=SQL_PUBLIC_CITY and cache2=SQL_PUBLIC_PERSON?
What is the version of ignite do you use? Do you make any changes in config, e.g. add NodeFilter?

Comment: I have tried your test and it seems to pass for me, no weird exceptions.

Comment: I changed my approach since to use node created by code (instead of using one started externally). I tried this example now and it works. I think it could have problems with 'ignite' folder in user temp area. I am not able to repeat it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly this error and fixed it by adding

```
Ignition.setClientMode(true);
```

before the call to `Ignition.start();`